# Can you do a loop to change array size depending on the number of photos in a file in javascript/php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, arrays

Sorry for the question isn't very clear, basically

I have got the php code to search for photos in the directory based on the userId given in the url. So if the userId = 1, it will go to Photos/1 and get all the photos in that directory and output it into an array that I can use in Javascript. It works.

I have an external javascript to my php/html code. 
I am changing the attr of the div's to display the photos. I have 5 "photo containers" in the array called photodisplay:

```
var photodisplay = 
[
    $("#photo1"),
    $("#photo2"),
    $("#photo3"),
    $("#photo4"),
    $("#photo5"),
];
```

Then I have a loop to change the attribute/img src:

```
function preloadingPhotos() {
for (var x=0; x<galleryarray.length; x++)
{
    photodisplay[x].attr("src", "Photos/" + userid + "/" + galleryarray[x]);
    console.log("preloaded photos");

}
displayPhoto();
}
```

It works. Providing no more than 5 photos because that is how many photocontainers I have. But what if I had photos? **The question is:** Would I be able to do a loop to keep changing the photos in the photodisplay array?

I also have code for the photocontainers to fade in and out:

`function displayPhoto(){`

```
photodisplay[0].fadeIn(3000);
photodisplay[0].delay(3000).fadeOut(3000, function() { //first callback func
photodisplay[1].fadeIn(3000);
photodisplay[1].delay(3000).fadeOut(3000, function() { //second callback func
photodisplay[2].fadeIn(3000);
photodisplay[2].delay(3000).fadeOut(3000, function() { //third callback func
photodisplay[3].fadeIn(3000);
photodisplay[3].delay(3000).fadeOut(3000, function() { // fourth callback func
photodisplay[4].fadeIn(3000);
photodisplay[4].delay(3000).fadeOut(3000, function() {
setTimeout(displayPhoto(), 3000);

});
}); 
});
}); 
});

}// end of function displayPhoto
```

Which requires me to manually enter the number of the array of the photodisplay.

I would thinking of adding more to the array with duplications of the photocontainers. But I don't think that would work since I would have to manually enter the number of the array in the code above to make it fade in and out.

Sorry if this is confusing. I tried my best to explain my problem. I hope someone can help. Don't worry about the retrieving images in the directory part, because it works. It increases the array of photos accordingly, I just don't know how to adjust this change with my javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The method you are using, does not scale as you have a callback function for every element in your slideshow.

What you should do, is put all images in a list (or a list of `div`'s) and hide them all / change the z-index so that only the active one shows. The you can loop through your elements using `.next()` on the list items to get the next one (or the first one if `.next().length` is 0).

This will clean up your code and is pretty easy to do yourself but there are also loads of jQuery plugins that do it for you.

Comment: So would I just need to change displayPhoto function or the preloadingPhoto function too? Because the preloadingPhoto function puts the images in a list... I'm confused :S sorry..

Comment: @fondillusions If you already have all images in the html source, you only need to change the javascript function.

Comment: The images are only added to the divs in the Javascript. In my html, I have the php code to get the images and to change it into an javascript array.

Answer (score 0):

You need a little bit of abstraction here. So instead of manually code numbers, try another approach. For this example I've used jQuery; since you've tagged your question with it, I assume it's okay:

```
// Set a default value and store the current photo in it.
var currentPhoto = 0;
// Calculate the total number of photos
var photoTotal = photodisplay.length;
var photoTimeout = false;
// Create a function to go to the next photo
var nextPhoto = function () {
  // Keep track of the new current
  currentPhoto = (currentPhoto + 1) % photoTotal;
  // Just to be sure clearTimeout
  clearTimeout(photoTimeout);
  // Fadein each photo; you might want to do something to reset the style
  photodisplay[0].fadeIn({
    duration: 3000,
    complete: function () {
      photoTimeout = setTimeout(nextPhoto, 3000);
    }
  });  
}

nextPhoto();
```

Comment: Thank you for your time in writing that code. I'm just confused to how to change my code now. I'm new to coding so not very good. I was thinking, would it work if I just manually go through the divs to add the photos in. So instead of photodisplay[x] and looping, do photodisplay for 0-4 and then surely it will just keep on adding the photos from the array to them after they have loaded? :S I don't know. Will try it now and see! Do you think you would be able to provide me with some contact detail so I can ask you for more help? :S Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to define JS from the backend like that; just have PHP render the markup, then use JS to query and parse the markup for the presentational layer.

Let's assume your markup looks like this:

```
  <div id="photocontainers">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>

  <!-- A hidden array of images. -->
  <div id="images">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100&text=1" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100&text=2" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100&text=3" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100&text=4" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100&text=5" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100&text=6" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100&text=7" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100&text=8" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100&text=9" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100&text=10" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100&text=11" />
  </div>
```

So your server renders this; #images is just a hidden container, that basically preloads all the image assets you'll cycle between in #photocontainers.

```
var cycleImages = function() {

  // Cache selectors that we'll need.
  var $photoContainers = $('#photocontainers').children(),
    $images = $('#images img'),

    // Use `.data()` to get the starting point, or set to 0
    // (if this is the first time the function ran).
    startImage = $images.data('nextImage') || 0;

  // Loop from the starting point, filling up the number of 
  // photocontainers in the DOM.
  for (var i = startImage; i < startImage + $photoContainers.length; i++) {

    var $targetImage = $images.eq(i % $images.length),
      $targetPhotoContainer = $photoContainers.eq(i - startImage);

    // Get rid of the current contents.
    $targetPhotoContainer.empty();

    // Clone the desired image, and append it into place.
    $targetImage.clone().appendTo($targetPhotoContainer).fadeOut(0).fadeIn();
  }

  // Let's figure out which starting image is next up, and store that
  // with `.data()`.
  var nextImage = startImage + $photoContainers.length;

  if (nextImage >= $images.length) {
    nextImage -= $images.length;
  }

  $images.data('nextImage', nextImage);
}

// When the DOM is ready, call the method, then
// call it again however often you'd like.

$(document).ready(function() {

  cycleImages();

  setInterval(function() {
    cycleImages();
  }, 3000);
});
```

Here's a plunkr showing that in action: http://plnkr.co/SumqkXYpRXcOqEhAPOHm

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

I have php code to retrieve the images from the directory into an array. Isn't that the same as putting it in the "hidden array" for the div? 

And where in cycleImages function do we change the attribute of the photcontainters? Sorry if these are stupid questions. I am just very confused.

Comment: Unless you have a really good reason for it, you shouldn't be making the user assemble these paths. Just render out the images you want as *real* markup, then you don't have to do all that reconstruction in the browser. You don't have to set attributes, since you're dealing with DOM elements that are already ready-to-go.

Comment: I am trying to personalise the content based on the user so that is why I have done the userId thing...